# Securing Admin on separate port

Tags: http-request

I am attempting to secure the admin pages (/admin/*) and login page (/user/login) to port 8443. I have successfully done that with the following in apache 2.4:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com:443
    ServerAlias drupal
    DocumentRoot "/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/example.com/current"
    <LocationMatch /(user|admin)>
            Require all denied
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8443>
    ServerName example.com:8443
    ServerAlias drupal
    DocumentRoot "/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/example.com/current"
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem I am having is when I go to https://www.example.com:8443/user/login and login, I am redirected to http://www.example.com:8443/user/1.

This creates a 400 error - Bad request. Trying to serve http content over a SSL port.

How do I tell drupal to stay on https protocol and remain on port 8443?

Comment: You could use one of the login redirect modules to define where you wanna get redirected to after login, for example to /admin/content.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer if there's a solution in apache. If not I will try this.

Comment: Regarding Apache you are better off asking on Stack Overflow I guess. As that's off-topic on Drupal Answers.

Comment: What I read on there was simply code the request to go to https. Since this is a core form, I am not able to easily rewrite where the request is going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't able to do this on a separate port, but for anyone who needs to secure the login page from public eye, this is what I did.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName example.com:443
  ServerAlias drupal
  DocumentRoot "/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/example.com/current"
  <LocationMatch /(user|admin)>
        Require all denied
        Require ip 10
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will require the user to be on a local IP. (I am in-housing the site, so when I access the site I'm on a local IP.)